# In iOS 7, how do you access the topLayoutGuide / bottomLayoutGuide in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, constraints, autolayout, ios7

Using Xcode 5, downloaded today. iOS 7. When I run app the table view header appears underneath the navigation bar, I don't mind it scrolling underneath the navbar but I'd like for it to appear unobstructed initially. I am trying to figure out how to use the topLayoutGuide mentioned in the iOS 7 transition guide, which says you can set a constraint relative to it, but doesn't explain how.

Anyone know?

Transition guide [here](http://www.idiscoverlearning.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/iOS-7-UI-Transition-Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just realized that my storyboard was still set to Xcode 4.6

You have to go to the File Inspector (icon that looks like a file icon in the right navigation panel in Xcode) and then under "Interface Builder Document" where it says "Opens in" change to Default (5.0) and / or "View as" iOS 7.0 and Later

Then your IB document will show the guides inside the left hand navigation panel under the view controller

[image]

Often if you select the view, and click the "Pin" button at the bottom right, pin the vertical spacing, and the dropdown will have an option to use the topLayoutGuide

In my Storyboard, was still have trouble getting my `UITableView` to pin the vertical spacing between the top of the table view and the top layout guide. Every time I control-dragged I would get it pinning to the bottom of the table view instead of the bottom. But then I tried manually dragging the table view so that it appeared below the nav bar in IB and then control-dragged and the vertical spacing finally worked.

Comment: However, every time I try to add a constraint to the vertical spacing between my table view and the top layout guide, for some reason interface builder sets it so the spacing is constrained between the bottom of the table view, and not the top. Seems like a bug?

Comment: The offered pin seems to be affected by which way you control drag, drag down and it pins downwards.

Comment: Does this only work in storyboards? I do not see those guides in xib.

Comment: Yes, appears to be only in storyboards, and maybe not for every type of view controller

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in Storyboard when I set the top bar to Opaque the top of the scrollView changed so that it wasn't obscured by the nav bar.  Makes sense, but it's unfortunate that you can't use a translucent nav bar and get the same effect.

Comment: You can, you just need to adjust the constraints.